# Add text to image using php gd and google webfonts

Tags: php, image-processing, webfonts

Is is possible if I want adding text to image with font from google webfonts? using PHP image GD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need the font as a ttf / otf in order to do that. There is no other way unfortunatelly - or better said, anything else you would try would be way overcomplicated for the result, don't even think about it.

**Later edit** You said you can download the ttf files, so all you need is: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

Comment: I can download google webfonts as ttf file, so is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

imagettftext does not works on WAMP server on windows. you have to download freetype and recompile. Sometimes, Wamp sucks.