# Captcha image generating problems when using font PHP

Tags: php, imagettftext

its working perfect, until i try to use a font for text.

This is my code.. The 3er line commented now is the one that works fine... but in this example im trying to replace this line with imagettftext.. not lucky.

Whats my error?

```
$newImage = imagecreatefromjpeg( "orsil_secure.jpg" ); 

$txtColor = imagecolorallocate($newImage, 0, 0, 0); 

//imagestring($newImage, 5, 10, 27, $ranStr,  $txtColor); 

imagettftext($newImage, 5, 10, 27, $txtColor, $font_path, $ranStr);

header( "Content-type: image/jpeg" ); 

imagejpeg($newImage);
```

Oh yes in the previous lines is the route to the font here:

```
// random number

$ranStr = md5(microtime()); 

$ranStr = substr($ranStr, 0, 6); 

// Set Path to Font File
  $font_path = 'captcha.TTF';
```

Comment: What error are you getting? and is the font path correct, have you tried an absolute path to the font?

Comment: when i use the imagestring () it works i see the image.. when i use imagettftext () i dont get anything.. not even using the recomendatios from putvande

Comment: do you get an error message? We need to know what "dont get anything" means, like do you get a blank image, the script prematurely ends etc

Comment: nope i got the break image icon in chrome..

Comment: Take out the header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); call so it will output the error message and browse to the image itself, you should then see the error message (assuming you do have display_errors on in php.ini otherwise you will have to look in your error logs.

Comment: If you haven't already, add `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script. Also, make sure the path to your font file is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the wrong parameters in your call to [imagettftext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php).

Presumably, the 5 corresponds to the font used in `imagestring`, but has no place in `imagettftext`. You also need to specify the size and angle.

For example:

```
imagettftext($newImage, 12, 45, 10, 27, $txtColor, $font_path, $ranStr);
                        ^^  ^^
                        ||  ||
                        ||   ------ angle
                        ----------- size
```

In this example:

> size=12px or 12pt, depending on whether you're using GD1 or GD2
>
> angle = 45°

Obviously, you'll want to use your own values here.

If it still isn't working, then it's likely that the path to your font file is wrong. Check to see if it's in the same folder as the PHP script.

Comment: I thik now its the route to the file... but the font is there Warning: imagettftext() [function.imagettftext]: Could not find/open font in /xxxxx/public_html/library/captcha.php on line 32..

Comment: its working now , but the font send a message insted of my code.. I think its not a "legal" font to use =( ... i take it from dafont.com do you know a good font site for this.. can i use google fonts?? i will link to the font XD

Comment: Google fonts should be fine, but you have to download the TTF files. See [Add text to image using php gd and google webfonts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6132827/911182)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a parameter in your `imagettftext`.
If you look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php it has `size`, `angle`, `x` and `y`.
You are missing one of the 4 (im guessing the `angle`).

So it needs to be something like:

```
imagettftext($newImage, 5, 0, 10, 27, $txtColor, $font_path, $ranStr);
```

Where 0 is for `angle`.

Comment: unfortunaly it did not work, when i use the imagestring () it works i see the image.. when i use imagettftext () i dont get anything.. not even using your recomendations

Comment: I thik now its the route to the file... but the font is there Warning: imagettftext() [function.imagettftext]: Could not find/open font in /xxxxx/public_html/library/captcha.php on line 32